# Multi threading with third party library in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm using two functions from a third party library currently in my application. The first function, aka .SourceMeasure basically collecting data from some hardware while the second function, aka .ComputeErrors is purely calculation based on the data collected from the first function. And the measure-calculate executions will be looped for 5 times.
I'm thinking create a multi thread to move the .ComputeErrors to the worker thread to save some times. 
Will there be a issue if the.SourceMeasure is in main thread and the .ComputeErrors in the worker thread and both of them coming from the same library?

```
//The execution is something like this..    
for (int i=0; z < 5; z++)
{
   Lib.SourceMeasure (data)
   Lib.ComputeErorrs (data)  //Want to put this in a separate thread
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, which library you're using, but it's almost sure that you can not start `Lib.ComputeErorrs()` until `Lib.SourceMeasure()` is still running, on the same data set.

What you can do is to set up a queue and two threads:

- The "measure thread":

  - create a data item
  - call `Lib.SourceMeasure()` on it
  - push data to a FIFO queue
- The "compute thread":

  - hang on some if the queue is empty
  - pick a data item from the queue
  - call `Lib.ComputeErorrs()` with the data

On result, the measurement and the computation will run parallel (but not the same items, measurement will be some ahead). All you need to find is a thread-safe queue.